# Usage of React HOC for Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I was referring to the below link (section : HOCs for Functional Components)
https://rossbulat.medium.com/how-to-use-react-higher-order-components-c0be6821eb6c

In the example, below is the code for the HOC;

```
//functional HOC with useState hook
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function withCountState(Wrapped) {
   return function (props) {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
      props['count'] = count;
      props['setCount'] = setCount;
      return <Wrapped {...props} />;
   }
}
```

Also, the Wrapped component code is as below;

```
const Wrapped = (props) =>  {
   const {count, setCount} = props;
   return(
     <div>
        <h1>Counter Functional Component</h1>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
           Increment count
        </button>
     </div>);
};
```

For applying HOC to , we use

```
const EnhancedWrapped = withCountState(Wrapped);
```

Now I have 2 questions;

1. For consuming this component, do we just say `<EnhancedWrapped>` may be in our App.js or do we need anything else?
2. What benefit do we really get out of creating this HOC?

Answer (score 3):

Viet has answered your questions. HOC is a way to make your components re-usable through composition. You can have other components which get wrapped by the HOC and now they would have access to the count and setCount functionality.

Depending upon what you are trying to accomplish, it's also a good idea to consider the pitfalls of HOC and consider alternate patterns such as :

- Render Props: [React Docs on Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)
- Using Custom Hooks over HOC [Article on custom hooks](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/react-hooks-and-component-composition)

When using React Hooks, I'd personally prefer making custom hooks over using HOCs. And depending upon the use case, you may want to check out if React Context would make sense if multiple components are going to need a shared state.

Comment: Thanks a lot...So if the other component wants the counter functionality and it uses the HOC, it seems like it while it would get the counter functionality, it won't have much control over the rendering itself (coz that is part of the HOC itself i.e. here rendering is inside Wrapped....So would that be normal HOC behavior ?

Comment: What the HOC does is simply to wrap your components and provide it certain common/re-usable props. In your example, the HOC wraps the "Wrapped" component and gives it the props: state and setState. In you example, the state is being defined inside the HOC itself and passed through to the children. Now from your Wrapped component you get access to the setState function and you can trigger it onClick of the button. When you do that, it triggers a state update for the whole component (HOC+children)...and that causes a re-render. So  Wrapped is controlling when it gets re-rendered...

Answer (score 0):

1. For consuming this component, do we just say  may be in our App.js or do we need anything else? Yes, just use HOC like any other JSX component.
2. What benefit do we really get out of creating this HOC? You can make it reusable. Let's say you want another component with different content inside, like , you could just create a new component by `const AnotherEnhancedWrapped = withCountState(AnotherWrapped);`

Comment: Thanks a lot...So for (2) are you are saying that we can also use <AnotherEnhancedWrapped /> anywhere else in App.js and we can get the count rendering/functionailty as well in that component (plus things specific to that component also)